# Xcode; no certificates; missing previous developer

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I have a tricky situation here. I have an app, where the previous developer is not available; so i can't get get an export of the certificate idenetifiers

```
The app already has an approved version on appstore
I would like to release an update, but as i mentioned i do not have any access to previous developer
```

I have so much confusion right now...

```
Can i remove the existing bundle in itunesconnect and recreate a new one    with the same bundle id?  So that i can submit a new version with the same  bundle it (create certificates and stuff from scratch) 

If at all i can remove, will this effect existing app in appstore? 

Is there any way i can create new provisioning profiles for the existing    certificates? (I tried, with the message missing private key)
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going through a similar situation myself, some research landed me on an Apple document that reads:
"
Important: Re-creating your development or distribution certificates doesn’t affect apps that you’ve submitted to the store nor does it affect your ability to update them.
"
So, it seems to me that I can recreate the certificates and the provisioning profiles without impacting the current App or its future updates.
Here´s the link : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW6

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will read through it. I hope I can do it. Thanks again